Increase of filament diameter near nozzle when printing long time
I own a Creality Ender 5 Plus printer, and I use 1.75 mm PLA filament made by ESUN.
When I print parts weighing less than 200 grams within a day using the standard quality settings (0.2 mm layer height and nozzle temperature of 210 °C), everything works fine. However, when I print larger and more time-consuming parts with the same settings, the filament diameter near the nozzle increases, causing issues like filament jams.
This problem is particularly noticeable when printing lightweight parts at high resolutions (e.g., 0.12 mm). How can I address this issue?"


What you describe (the increased diameter of the filament) is the result of the problem called "heat creep".
Heat creep occurs when insufficient hotend cooling, incorrect retraction, or too less filament flow passes the hotend (low speeds nd low layer heights).
You should first fix the retraction, print at higher filament flows and alternatively provide better cooling of the hotend.
This is a particular problem that also arises when people are putting enclosures around the printers (this isn't mentioned in the question), but raising the anclosure temperature also causes exactly the same result; insuffisient cooling causing heat creep.

To address heat creep, I reduced the nozzle and bed temperatures by 5°C. Additionally, I adjusted the cooling settings in the software and relocated the printer to an environment with better air circulation. Despite continuous printing for two days, the printer is functioning well.
